# Ruby serialport randomly misses bytes

Tags: ruby, serial-port

Someone using the serialport library noticed that or it's just me? I found (very) few people in the same situation but I got no solution.

Here is an example of what I get with ruby serialport:

ff d8 ff e0 00 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a ff db 00 43 00 10 0c 0c 0e 0c 0a 10 0e 0e 0e 12 12 10 14 18 28 1a 18 16 16 18 32 24 26 1e 28 3a 34 3e 3c 3a 34 38 38 40 48 5c 4e 40 44 58 46 38 38 50 6e 52 58 60 62 68 68 68 3e 4e 72 7a 70 64 78 5c 66 68 64 ff db 00 43 01 12 12 12 16 16 16 30 1a 1a 30 64 42 38 42 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 36 00

Here is an example of what I get with gtkterm, at the same time!

ff d8 ff e0 00 **`11`** 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a ff db 00 43 00 10 0c 0c 0e 0c 0a 10 0e 0e 0e 12 12 10 14 18 28 1a 18 16 16 18 32 24 26 1e 28 3a 34 3e 3c 3a 34 38 38 40 48 5c 4e 40 44 58 46 38 38 50 6e 52 58 60 62 68 68 68 3e 4e 72 7a 70 64 78 5c 66 68 64 ff db 00 43 01 12 12 12 16 16 16 30 1a 1a 30 64 42 38 42 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 36 00

I'm using an FTDI breakout and a device with an uart interface. It seems to be random :( it's serialport-1.0.4 which I installed with "sudo gem install serialport".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you stumbled upon this in your researches, but this article mentions a modification to serialport.c that fixes the bug: [Ruby, Ruby-SerialPort and the missing bytes](http://blog.defv.be/2006/11/22/ruby-ruby-serialport-and-the-missing-bytes)

Here's the text from the link in case it ever goes down:

> So what did I do to make it work with ruby-serialport? I made a small
>   change to the serialport.c file:
>
> ```
> --- ruby-serialport-0.6/serialport.c    2003-02-13 20:55:48.000000000 +0100
> +++ ruby-serialport-0.6-new/serialport.c        2006-11-22 17:04:37.000000000 +0100
> @@ -608,7 +608,7 @@ static VALUE sp_create(class, _port)
>    break;
>    }
> -  fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
> +  fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);
>    if (fd == -1)
>    rb_sys_fail(port);
>    if (!isatty(fd)) {
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks, let me know if someone found a way to avoid that. Anyway I'll try later and give the results.

Comment: Yay it worked! In fact that's not much pain: you just need to:

Comment: $ unpack serialport
$ do the modification
$ gem build serialport.gemspec
$ gem install ./serialport.gem
That's all! Something i did not understand is that it worked only after I restarted my computer, which means I'm probably missing something after gem install. Just leave a comment if you know!

Thanks for your help

Comment: Tried this fix but still missing bytes for me. It is consistent, but no apparent rhyme or reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT same issue - consistently missing the same bytes. I narrowed it down to `0x11` and `0x13`, which I notice is also what you are missing.

The problem is that these ASCII characters are used for software flow control. The `SerialPort` instance has software flow control on by default, which filters out these bytes. You must manually disable it:

```
    @serial = SerialPort.new(port, :baudrate => baud)
    @serial.flow_control = SerialPort::NONE
```